# Create complex type of SP in EF which uses exec sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, complextype

I have a stored procedure something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserData]
    (@departmentId varchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    Set FMTONLY off

    declare @sql nvarchar(Max)
    Set @sql = 'select * from Users where DepartmentId in ('+@departmentId+'))'

    exec sp_executesql @sql
```

When I try to add this stored procedure to EF and create a complex type out of it, I get an error:

> Selected procedure or function returns no column

`SET FMTONLY`off also doesn't helps

This table has 25 columns and creating complex type manually will be a burden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you do - do not write code like that, a UK company got a SQL injection attack that has cost it around £35 million.

In your code I can write any injection I want into @departmentid parameter and you'll just execute it for me!

To answer your question - it's probably because there isn't actually a result from that stored procedure until it is actually executed.

Comment: any solution for this??

Comment: Do it differently, don't use dynamic SQL and instead split the @departmentid parameter into a # table and use that instead: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View5C09B52C-4600-4B66-9DD7-DCE840D64CBD.htm